# Controlling access rights on PD that is shared between several Kubernetes services

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a PD that is shared between two Kubernetes services. Once service runs a server application inside a container currently as `root` (I will probably change this to, say, `user1`), the other service runs Docker's [Postgres image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) as `postgres`. I would like to make sure that both `root` (eventually `user1`) and `postgres` have read-write access to certain directories below the PD's mount point, for instance `postgres` should "own" the directory `/mnt/disk/my-pd/pgdata`.

Can this be configured on the level of a Kubernetes spec? If not and if I have to configure it manually "outside", can I make assumptions about how UIDs and GIDs relate to each other throughout the cluster, i.e. does Kubernetes (or do standard Docker images such as `postgres`) include some kind of directory service that would keep the UID e.g. for `postgres` in sync throughout the cluster?

Here is the Postgres-related portion of my spec in its current form:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: postgres-deployment
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres-container
        image: postgres
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: my-secret
              key: postgres-password.txt
        - name: PGDATA
          value: /mnt/disk/my-pd/pgdata
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          value: mydb
        ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          containerPort: 5432
        volumeMounts:
        - name: my-volume
          mountPath: /mnt/disk/my-pd
      volumes:
      - name: my-volume
        gcePersistentDisk:
          pdName: my-pd
          fsType: ext4
```

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317295/docker-postgres-mounting-an-existing-database-within-a-dockerized-postgresql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [solution](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/2630) consisted of specifying a security context that references GID 999 (appended to the original spec):

```
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 999
```

The [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/9.5/Dockerfile) for the official [`postgres`](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) Docker image explicitly sets
GID 999.